# How can I improve this calculator (Bluej)?

Tags: java, bluej

I am quite new to java and I wanted to create a calculator in bluej, but it should work for complex equations like "8/2+6*3". So I used string for this and created this:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class CulCulLator {
    public static void CulCulLate() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String e = input.nextLine();
        int l1 = e.length();
        int c = 0;

        double pos = 0;
        double x;
        boolean add = false;
        boolean mul = false;
        boolean div = false;
        boolean min = false;
        int art = 0;
        double value = 0;
        double bvd = 0;
        char num;
        int ad, mi, di, mu, ads;
        ad = 0;
        mi = 0;
        mu = 0;
        di = 0;
        ads = 0;
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char bc : e.toCharArray()) {
            chars.add(bc);
        }

        int l = chars.size();
        int l2 = l - 1;
        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        while (c <= l2) {
            num = chars.get(c);
            switch (num) {
                case '1':
                    pos = pos + 1;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '2':
                    pos = pos + 2;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '3':
                    pos = pos + 3;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '4':
                    pos = pos + 4;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '5':
                    pos = pos + 5;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '6':
                    pos = pos + 6;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '7':
                    pos = pos + 7;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '8':
                    pos = pos + 8;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '9':
                    pos = pos + 9;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '0':
                    pos = pos + 0;
                    if (c == l2) {

                        list.add(pos);
                        pos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case '+':
                    add = true;
                    ad += 1;

                    pos = pos / 10;

                    list.add(pos);
                    list.add(7415.5273);

                    pos = 0;
                    ads += 1;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    mul = true;
                    mu += 1;
                    ad += 1;
                    pos = pos / 10;

                    list.add(pos);
                    list.add(7415.5278);

                    pos = 0;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    min = true;
                    ad += 1;
                    pos = pos / 10;

                    list.add(pos);
                    list.add(9131.975);

                    pos = 0;
                    mi += 1;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    div = true;
                    ad += 1;
                    pos = pos / 10;

                    list.add(pos);
                    list.add(9131.9724);

                    di += 1;
                    pos = 0;
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong input");
                    art = +1;
                    break;
            }

            pos = pos * 10;
            c++;
        }
        int l3 = list.size() - 1;

        if (div) {
            int d = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int gf;
            int fg;
            double pio;
            double iop;
            double diver;


            while (n < di) {
                d = list.indexOf(9131.9724);

                gf = d - 1;
                fg = d + 1;
                pio = list.get(gf);
                iop = list.get(fg);
                diver = pio / iop;
                list.remove(fg);
                list.remove(d);
                list.remove(gf);

                list.add(gf, diver);
                n++;
                l3--;
            }

        }
        if (mul) {
            int d = 0;
            int n = 0;
            double diver;
            double iop;
            double pio;
            int gf;
            int fg;

            while (n < mu) {
                d = list.indexOf(7415.5278);
                gf = d - 1;
                fg = d + 1;
                pio = list.get(fg);
                iop = list.get(gf);
                diver = pio * iop;
                list.remove(fg);
                list.remove(d);
                list.remove(gf);
                list.add(gf, diver);
                n++;
                l3--;
            }

        }
        if (add) {
            int d = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int gf;
            int fg;
            double pio;
            double iop;
            double diver;

            while (n < ads) {
                d = list.indexOf(7415.5273);

                gf = d - 1;
                fg = d + 1;
                pio = list.get(fg);
                iop = list.get(gf);
                diver = pio + iop;
                list.remove(fg);
                list.remove(d);
                list.remove(gf);

                list.add(gf, diver);
                n++;
                l3--;
            }

        }
        if (min == true) {
            int d = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int gf;
            int fg;
            double pio;
            double iop;
            double diver;

            while (n < mi) {
                d = list.indexOf(9131.975);

                gf = d - 1;
                fg = d + 1;
                pio = list.get(fg);
                iop = list.get(gf);
                diver = iop - pio;
                list.remove(fg);
                list.remove(d);
                list.remove(gf);
                list.add(gf, diver);
                n++;
                l3--;
            }

        }
        value = list.get(0);
        System.out.println(value);

    }

}
```

It worked fine but I just wanted to know that how can I improve my code like in place of **list.add(7415.5273)**, is there any function that can add character '+' and then add the numbers because the ArrayList do not allow to add characters in Double type . Thanks!

Comment: You can improve it significantly by modularizing it, breaking it into smaller functions, and adding comments. It's difficult for me to read this code

Comment: You don't need the case statements for 0..9. Your calculator doesn't handle parentheses or operator precedence, and to fix that you will have to throw it all away and start again.